# AnyObject is not convertible to String

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

The code below returns the error "AnyObject is not convertible to String" :

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Podcast")
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Podcast")
    query.selectKeys(["name", "artist" ])
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let name: NSArray = objects as NSArray
            println("objects \(name)")
            cell.textLabel?.text = name["name"]
        }
    }
```

if I add "as NSString" next to "name["name"]". then I get the error "type Int does not confirm to StringLiteralConvertible"

Any ideas please? I am pulling data from Parse.

Comment: There is some confusion here.  If `name` is an `NSArray`, why are you treating it like a dictionary `name["name"]`?  You index arrays with an `Int` and not strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`name["name"]` will return a value of type `AnyObject?`.  It is optional because dictionary
look ups always return optionals since the key might be invalid.  You should conditionally
cast it to type `NSString` which is an object type and then use optional binding (`if let`)
to bind that to a variable in the case where the loop up does not return `nil`:

```
if let myname = name["name"] as? NSString {
    cell.textLabel?.text = myname
}
```

or if you want to use an empty string if "name" is not a valid key, the *nil coalescing operator* `??` comes in handy:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = (name["name"] as? NSString) ?? ""
```

Comment: Unfortunately Xcode suggests "as!" instead of "as?", where the latter can be used in guard statements as well as if-let's

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3

```
cell.textLabel?.text = name["name"] as! String?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
`cell.textLabel?.text = name["name"] as String`

Hope it Helps!